# Alternating command

Tags: macros, tex-core

Is it possible to have a command alternate its behaviour?

My idea is something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def \current {c}

\def \abc {
    \ifx\current{a}
        \def\current{b}
    \else
        \ifx\current{b}
           \def\current{c}
        \else
           \def\current{a}
        \fi
    \fi     
    \current       
}

\begin{document}
    \abc \abc \abc
\end{document}
```

I'd expect this to output a b c, but instead I get:

[image]

I'm guessing that the logic inside is only run when the `\abc` is being defined, and that's why it's always stuck at a. How can I write something with the desired behaviour?

Comment: no the expression inside a command definition is not evaluated at all (the replacement text can use undefined commands and there is no error if the command is not used)

Comment: You've fallen in the [XY problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/134574) fallacy :-) It's usually best not to edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. In such cases it's best to ask a new question altogether

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Will do so :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik actually it was only a minor tweak here I edited the answer to match

Comment: @LukeCollins Thanks! Though David was faster :-) Seems like I caused a big mess with one single comment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 \ifx\current{
```

compares `\current` against `{`  which is not what you intended,

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\currenta{a\let\abc\currentb}
\def\currentb{b\let\abc\currentc}
\def\currentc{c\let\abc\currenta}
\let\abc\currenta


\begin{document}
    \abc \abc \abc
\end{document}
```

For the updated case note that the argument of `\color` has to *expand* to a name, so can not have assignments, and the tikz for loop groups each iteration so you need a global assignmet

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{0,114,206}
\definecolor{myYellow}{RGB}{255,199,44}
\definecolor{myBrown}{RGB}{154,51,36}

\def\currentblue{\color{myBlue}\global\let\currentcol\currentyellow}
\def\currentyellow{\color{myYellow}\global\let\currentcol\currentbrown}
\def\currentbrown{\color{myBrown}\global\let\currentcol\currentblue}
\global\let\currentcol\currentblue

\begin{document}
    \tikz{
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
            \node at (\i,\i) {\currentcol \i};
        }}
\end{document}
```