# Alternating *colour* command

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, color

I asked a simplified version of this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528032/alternating-command), but unfortunately in constructing my MWE, some detail seems to have been lost.

My *actual* goal is to create a command which alternates colours. I've tried the solution suggested by David Carlisle in his answer to that question, but this didn't work in my case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\currentred{red\let\currentcol\currentgreen}
\def\currentgreen{green\let\currentol\currentblue}
\def\currentblue{blue\let\currentcol\currentred}
\let\currentcol\currentred

\begin{document}
    \tikz{
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
            \node at (\i,\i) {\color{\currentcol} \i}
        }}
\end{document}
```

This gives a "TeX capacity exceeded" error.

Comment: note I'd answered this question in the other post before you posted here but it doesn't matter, accepts that cat's answer here he/she/it does know something about tikz:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you load Ti*k*Z you have access to the pgf machinery which contains access to arrays and modulo functions. To cycle through the list of colors,

```
\def\LstColors{"myBlue","myYellow","myBrown"}
```

all you need to do is to say

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[Mod(\i-1,3)]}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{0,114,206}
\definecolor{myYellow}{RGB}{255,199,44}
\definecolor{myBrown}{RGB}{154,51,36}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\LstColors{"myBlue","myYellow","myBrown"}
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[Mod(\i-1,3)]}
            \node[color=\mycolor] at (\i,\i) {\i};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid quirks with quotes, `\pgfmathparse` and `\def` by using `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{0,114,206}
\definecolor{myYellow}{RGB}{255,199,44}
\definecolor{myBrown}{RGB}{154,51,36}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setcolorlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_luke_colorlist_seq { #1 }
  % sequences are indexed from 1, so transfer the last item to the left
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_luke_colorlist_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_put_left:NV \l_luke_colorlist_seq \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getcolor}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \l_luke_colorlist_seq
   {% mod out and add one
    \int_mod:nn { #1 } { \seq_count:N \l_luke_colorlist_seq } + 1
   }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_luke_colorlist_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setcolorlist{myBlue,myYellow,myBrown}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
    \node[color=\getcolor{\i}] at (\i/2,\i/2) {\i};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setcolorlist{myBlue,myYellow}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
    \node[color=\getcolor{\i}] at (\i/2,\i/2) {\i};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can define a color list inside `tikzpicture` and it will be available only locally, or a “global” one by setting it in the document preamble; such global list can always be overridden locally.

[image]